# Out-of-line definition of base class' nested class

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, clang, nested-class

Is the following code valid?

```
struct A 
{
    struct nested;
};

struct B : public A {};

struct B::nested {};
```

gcc accepts it, but clang rejects it with the following error:

```
test.cpp:8:14: error: no struct named 'nested' in 'B'
    class B::nested {};
          ~~~^
```

Comment: I don't think A's private `nested` class is visible to B.

Comment: @franji1: I don't think it has anything to do with visibility. I changed the classes to structs and clang still rejects it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, it's invalid.  Here's the quote.

Section 9 paragraph 11, emphasis mine:

> If a *class-head-name* contains a *nested-name-specifier*, the *class-specifier* shall refer to a class that was **previously declared directly in the class or namespace to which the *nested-name-specifier* refers**, or in an element of the inline namespace set (7.3.1) of that namespace (i.e., not merely inherited or introduced by a *using-declaration*), and the *class-specifier* shall appear in a namespace enclosing the previous declaration.  In such cases, the *nested-name-specifier* of the *class-head-name* of the definition shall not begin with a *decltype-specifier*.

In your example, the *class-head-name* is the tokens `B::nested`, which comprises the *nested-name-specifier* `B::` and the *class-name* `nested`.  The *class-specifier* is the entire `struct B::nested {` ... `}`.

Answer (score 1):

B has no nested class named `nested`.  only A has a nested class named `nested`   `class A::nested { };` should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

You inherit from `A` so you don't encapsulated `nested` struct in `B`.

From created struct of type `B` you can only reach struct named `nested` as it is part of struct `B`, however to construct struct named `nested` is responsible `A`, because it encapsulated `nested`.

All-in-all your code is invalid.